# C++ declared constant named the same as a defined constant

Tags: macros, autoconf, automake

Is there a standard or good way of avoiding declared constants being named the same as a defined constant.

My Problem,

Im trying to compile my program using autoconf in linux which defines VERSION but in one of Mongo's db header files they declare a constant named VERSION. There's obviously a problem naming a variable using a right hand value.

Normally I would just change the name but in this case its not my library. I could figure out how to rename the defined variable autoconf.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a very good suggestions, but depending on the size of the library, you could go through all the files and manually replace all references to VERSION with a more appropriately named variable using the Find and Replace tool. For larger libraries, obviously, this would be inappropriate.

Comment: Are you asking a question about the language or just about how to avoid the situation with autoconf?

Comment: Doug, avoiding this situation in autoconf mainly. Im switching my code base to autoconf and this is an error ive encountered.

Comment: Elliot, Yes I could. That is how I confirmed the issue but that would cause issues when I want to upgrade mongo's lib and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `no-define` along with `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in your `configure.ac` file.

> By default this macro AC_DEFINE's PACKAGE and VERSION. This can be
>   avoided by passing the no-define option, as in:
>
> `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([gnits 1.5 no-define dist-bzip2])`

See [Automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Public-Macros.html).

Comment: Great thanks, does automake use the VERSION for any thing or is it just for use in the users code base. If thats the case I could use AC_DEFINE(PROG_VERSION, "5.6") to define it to something else.

Comment: I think those defines are still there for legacy reasons. I might be wrong, but afaik `PACKAGE_NAME` and `PACKAGE_VERSION` are those used by deb tools for instance when creating packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you've localized the error, you can do something like this:

```
const unsigned int OLD_VERSION = VERSION;
#undef VERSION
#include <mongodb_header.h>
```

and then use `OLD_VERSION` in your code, instead of `VERSION`. Or just define your version in another namespace.

Also, file a bug in Mongodb. This is not the correct behavior of using just `VERSION` as a name in the outer namespace. It should check at least if `VERSION` is already defined, or prefix the variable such as `MONGODB_VERSION`, or something like that.

Comment: See my answer for the proper way to solve OP's problem. Beside that, I would recommend against `#undef`, prefer `#pragma push_macro("macro_name")` and `#pragma pop_macro("macro_name")` when your compiler supports it.

Comment: Mmm... this have some disadvantage. What if he or she actually wants the variable VERSION in the program? Adding `no-define` to `AM_INIT...` does not add the variable. He or she can add it manually, but I think the thing here is to overcome a badly written `.h` file that pollutes (in any way) the outer namespace. As for push and pop macro, they are nice. I didn't know them, but I wonder how portable they are...

Comment: Diego, I dont think mongo is polluting the outer namespace the problem is they'r using a common defined constant. They have it wrapped in a mongo namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no good way to safeguard yourself against what some 3rd party library might pollute the global namespace with. This is why god invented namespaces.

You can use namespaces if VERSION is a global symbol known at compile time:

```
namespace yourStuff
{
    int VERSION;

    // references to VERSION here refer to the inner VERSION, not ::VERSION
}
```

but if VERSION is a preprocessor macro (as I suspect with its capitalization) then it doesn't follow any compilation rules and exists outside the rules of the compiler. You can detect it with other preprocessor macros:

```
#ifdef VERSION
 // define it to be something else
#else
#endif
```

(or use #undef like in Diego's answer to kill it)

But doing that everywhere VERSION is references will get nasty. You'll just need to not use VERSION.